# Proving that a function is an automorphism

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Suppose $G$ is a group. For each $g\in G$  we define the function $\phi_g(x) : G\to G$ as $\phi(x) = g^{-1}xg$. Prove that $\phi_g(x)$ is an automorphism of $G$.

This is what I did ( But I don't know if it's right ):

The only possibility for me that $\phi$ being an automorphism was if it's an identity function . So:

$$\begin{align}
\phi_g(g)& = g^{-1}gg\\
 \phi_g(g) &= (g^{-1}g)g\\
 \phi_g(g) &= eg\\
 \phi_g(g)& = g.
\end{align}$$

But at the same time this doesn't seem quite right for me...

Comment: No, there is no reason that $\phi$ must be the identity in order to be an automorphism.  Moreover, your argument only shows that $\phi(g)=g$, which does not mean that $\phi$ is the identity.

Comment: Show that it's surjective, injective, and a homomorphism. Also, this has been answered like a million times on the internet, just search Google for "prove conjugation is automorphism"

Comment: The notation here is a bit of a culprit as well. $\phi$ is 'indexed' by $g$, so there's not a _single_ $\phi()$; instead it would be better (for the book) to write something like 'for each $g\in G$ we define the function $\phi_g(x): G\mapsto G$ as $\phi_g(x)=g^{-1}xg$'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki That was my mistake. The function is written in the way that you mentioned. I'm gonna fix that.  :p.

Comment: Some duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364864/inner-automorphisms-with-groups and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411717/group-of-inner-automorphisms-of-a-group-g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $g\in G$. The function $\phi:G\to G$ is injective and well-defined because for all $x,y$ we have

$$\begin{align}
x=y&\iff g^{-1}x=g^{-1}y\\
&\iff g^{-1}xg=g^{-1}yg\\
&\iff \phi(x)=\phi(y).
\end{align}$$

It is surjective because, for any $h\in G$, we have $h=g^{-1}(ghg^{-1})g=\phi(ghg^{-1})$ while $ghg^{-1}\in G$.

It is a homomorphism, too, since for any $a,b\in G$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\phi(ab)&=g^{-1}(ab)g\\
&=g^{-1}a(gg^{-1})bg\\
&=(g^{-1}ag)(g^{-1}bg)\\
&=\phi(a)\phi(b).
\end{align}$$

Hence $\phi$ is an isomorphism from $G$ to $G$; that is, $\phi$ is an automorphism.